# VBA: Why chrW(ascW("è")) displays ï¿½ instead of è?

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

If e.g. I evaluate `ChrW(AscW("R"))` the result on my screen is displayed as R, which makes sense.
However, if I use a special letter, like è, the expression `ChrW(AscW("è"))` displays ï¿½ instead of è. Can anybody please explain why?

I am trying to display in a VBA message box the character "è" but neither of the codes below work:

```vb
MsgBox "è"             'I get � instead
MsgBox ChrW(232)       'I get ï¿½ instead
```

Any advice to display "è" instead of those strange characters?

Comment: ï¿½ is the same as �, encoded in utf-8 and interpreted as code page 1252.  MsgBox() looks like a fib, more likely to be caused by a file.  Could be the source file for "è", but not for ChrW(232).

Comment: seems an encoding discrepancy between your system and VBA code / editor. Try,```Option Explicit``` and ```Option Base As Binary```, 
at the beginning of your module, which is just a workaround in your case.

Comment: @Derby9421 `Option Explicit` has nothing to do with encodings, and `Option Base As Binary` is not valid code (`Option Base 1` or `Option Compare Binary` would be, but they have nothing to do with encodings either).